# Change the speed of animation at runtime in unity c#

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

**I want to change the speed of animation to my desired speed during runtime of a program.** *I have an c# script and animator controller attached to the game object.* The default speed of animation in unity is **1**. I set the default speed value of animation to **0.3f**. And during runtime of program, I want the speed of animation to **1**.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class wowBoard : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    Animator anim;
    bool changeSpeed;
   void Start()
   {
      anim=GetComponent<Animator>();
     playAnim();
     changeSpeed=false;
    }

   public void playAnim()
   {
     anim.SetBool("show",true);
   }

   void Update()
  {
     if(changeSpeed)
        playChangeSpeedAnim();

   }

 public void playChangeSpeedAnim()
 {
    anim.speed=1;
    anim.SetBool("show",true);
 }
}
```

The speed of animation did not get change to 1 even boolean value of **changeSpeed** is **true**.

Comment: Finally I got the solution of my problem with the same code mentioned above. The only change is in parameter of animation state which need to be true by default. Previously my animation parameter "show" is false by default.

Answer (score 36):

To manipulate the animation speed you can use the Speed multiplier parameter field in the animation properties.

If you select the animation in the animator, you will see this in the inspector:

[image]

If you click on the "Parameter" checkbox, the Multiplier option will be enabled. In the Multiplier field, you can select a float type parameter, and the animation speed will be set the parameter's value.

So, you can just create a new float parameter named `speed`, and change the speed of the animation to X through script by just executing `anim.SetFloat("speed", X);`

Answer (score 20):

Using the Animator Window, while the object that owns the Animator component is selected, first add a parameter using the little `+` sign next to the search field.

[image: Adding a Parameter To Animator To Control Animation Speeds]

Here I called it `animSpeed` and gave it a value of `1.0` to start with.
Then select the state that contains the animation you want to change according to your `animSpeed` parameter and, in the Inspector, under **Speed**, tick the Parameter checkbox next to **Multiplier** and make sure the parameter that drives the speed is selected, so `animSpeed` in our example.

[image: Animator: changing the speed multiplier with a custom parameter]

On the code side, you'll have a script that holds a reference to an Animator type. In C# words:

```
 [SerializeField] Animator mainAnimator;
```

Plus, you would have, for example, a variable to set the animation speed (this value could come from anywhere but for simplicity we expose it to the inspector to test quickly):

```
[SerializeField, Range(0.01f, 2f)] float animSpeedControl = 1f;
```

Later in the code, likely in the `Update`, you can finally set the Animator's parameter using its name (but there are other method overloads available):

```
mainAnimator.SetFloat("animSpeed", animSpeedControl);
```

Comment: That's one way to do it, but it doesn't explain why `anim.speed` isn't working.  What is that property for, if it doesn't control the speed of the animation?

Comment: @user2102929 That is the way to do it if you have an Animator component and not an Animation component. The asker has an Animator component. The property animSpeed does control the animation speed by acting as multiplier. Did you try it?

Comment: Great answer, the pictures are most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

You are changing the speed of your Animator object, not your current animation.

There are two possible solutions for this:

1. Obtain your current Animation object running and change its speed. Something like:

i.e:

```
animation["My animation name"].speed = 1f;
```

2. Build **two** animation clips inside your animator (one running at .3f and other at 1f), and make them be triggered depending on your **speed** value. Then, you just need to change the speed value to make Animator switch between one or the  other:

i.e:

```
anim.SetFloat("speed", 1f);
```

or

```
anim.SetFloat("speed", .3f);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, your first option did not work for me. And the second option is a little bit repeating process when there are many animation. **Finally I got the solution of my problem with the same code mentioned above. The only change is in parameter of animation state which need to be true by default.** Previously my animation parameter "show" is false by default.